# Problem with 'fputcsv' repeating the same variable

Tags: php, html, arrays, fputcsv

Iv been trying to have data from my array variables sent into a .txt file. the variables are working as intended since iv already managed to code in 3 products that a user can choose from, then use a form to submit the quantity and they all individually appear with the movie name and quantity separately. But when i cant seem to figure out a way to fputcsv send the movie names and quantity for each movie separately, i just repeats the last movie and quantity for every line, then when i submit the next movie and quantity it over-rides the last one.

My code for cart page (not showing all the code since most is css, the if/else statements were just me trying desperately to at least get the 2nd movie name out)

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
var_dump ($_POST);
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
$_SESSION['cart']=[];
}
$cart = &$_SESSION['cart'];
$movieName = $_POST['movie_name'];
$quantity = $_POST['qty'];

if(isset($movieName)) {
$currentQuantity = $cart[$movieName];
$cart[$movieName] = $currentQuantity + $quantity;
} else {
$cart[$movieName] = $quantity;

}
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>

<?php
$list = array
(
"$movieName,$quantity",
"$movieName,$quantity",
"$movieName,$quantity",
);

$file = fopen("orders.txt","w");

foreach ($list as $line)
if ($movieName = 'Game of Thrones: Season 1') {

}
 else if ($movieName = 'Friends Season 1') {

  }
 else  if ($movieName = 'Inception') {

    }

  {
  fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));
  }

fclose($file); ?>
```

one of the forms submitting data:

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="movie_name" value= "Game of Thrones: Season 1" />
   <input type = "hidden" name = "id" value = "M01" />
   <br>

<div class="widthc">
   <button class="prod" id="minus">−</button>
<input type="number" name="qty" value="0" id="qty" min="0" max="15"/>
<button class="prod" id="plus">+</button>
<br><br>
<button class="prod" type="submit">  Submit</button>
</form>
```

If there is any other code u want/need to see just let me know and ill edit my post to include it. Thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: Can you explain a bit about what the business process is? It looks like you're adding an item to the cart, but also saving the cart to a text file. What's the purpose of doing that here rather than in a check out process? Is the intention to dump the cart out to the file each time something is added to the cart, and that file should always represent the state of the cart? Is the file shared among all users of the site, or is the actual file path specific to a session? I'm having trouble picturing how this would work in the real world.

Comment: the top piece of code is currently in the cart.php page, but after thinking about i decided to move it to the checkout.php (they have the same array code so it shouldn't change much just need to move fputscv code). the purpose is to have it write out every order into the txt file, it would be nice if it wrote every users oreder into that file, but as long as it writes 1 users at a time it should be good enough for now. Sorry i should of went more into detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many little things in this code seem wrong or show just a lack of understanding. Some may be due to "sample" code.

Either way, let me go over it in chunks.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
var_dump ($_POST);
```

Closing and opening a new PHP block is just pointless. This could be due to sample code for the question (or not). Either way it should be just :

```
<?php
session_start();

// debug
var_dump ($_POST);
```

Nothing really wrong on the next chunk. Personally I do not like it (ie; create a new var for something that already exists, even with a reference) but each to their own.

```
if(! isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart']=[];
}
$cart = &$_SESSION['cart'];
$movieName = $_POST['movie_name'];
$quantity = $_POST['qty'];
```

This next bit I'm not 100% confident on. You have created `$movieName` above from the value of `$_POST['movie_name']`. I believe even if that value is a blank string, your `isset()` will return `true`. Either way the result may still work as expect.

```
if(isset($movieName)) {
    $currentQuantity = $cart[$movieName]; 
    $cart[$movieName] = $currentQuantity + $quantity;
} else {
    $cart[$movieName] = $quantity;
}
```

If the lodgic is sound, the following line change would remove a pointless creation of a var.

```
//$currentQuantity = $cart[$movieName]; 
$cart[$movieName] += $quantity;
```

Another close and open PHP block that could be removed

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
?> 
<?php
```

Now to the real issue. You are creating an array with repeated elements:

```
$list = array (
    "$movieName,$quantity",
    "$movieName,$quantity",
    "$movieName,$quantity",
);
```

The above code block would make 3 elements in the array, all with the same values - they would be all identical values of the current `$movieName` and `$quantity`.

I think what you really wanted to do was something more like:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k => $v) {
    if ($v > 0) {
         $list[] = array($k,$v);
    }
}
```

This next part is interesting due to the errors. The first question is why do you hard-code a variable name?

And then the next question is did you really mean to use `=` instead of `==` in the `if` statement?

```
$file = fopen("orders.txt","w");

foreach ($list as $line) {
    if ($movieName = 'Game of Thrones: Season 1') {
        // do nothing? Really?
    } else if ($movieName = 'Friends Season 1') {
        // do nothing? Really?
    } else  if ($movieName = 'Inception') {
        // do nothing? Really?
    }
}

fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));
fclose($file);
```

I think what you wanted here was more like:

```
// To overwrite, use 'w'
$fp = fopen('orders.csv', 'w');
// Or (as noted by Rob) to append to the file, use 'a'
//$fp = fopen('orders.csv', 'a');
// For other options see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: This it pretty much the answer I was writing. The only thing I would add is,  you may want to check the mode the file is being opened in  - "w" will truncate the file. If you're appending to an existing file, use "a".

Comment: i just finished reading your post, first off thank you for taking the time to reply in such detail. I havent tried the code yet but i thought i could atleast reply to some of your questions on the errors. Most of the errors are as you said, its due to just using sample codes and playing around with them till i figured it out to work for my site, and some are just because im still in my first year of I.T and these concepts are new to me, and iv been having trouble wrapping my head around some of these things. Once again thanks for the detailed reply, i need to look into these topics more.